# peerjs only run on localhost but not working on remote hosting

Tags: webrtc, peerjs

I create a chat video website using Peerjs and Webrtc , It run on localhost but when deploying remote hosting not working . Help me !

Comment: More information please - are you running your own peerjs server, or relying on the public one?

Comment: If your server is running on https you will need to run your peerjs server on https also, although it may be possible to stick with http if you can do the work to enable cors for it.

Comment: There may be a reason that the ports you are using may not been configured to access outside.

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with the same problem before. Now I know the problem and could solve it to some extent. Looking forward for better option. I am sharing my solution. It may help you and it may help me if anyone gets better.
Problems:
1. The cloud server currently does not support https.
2. Lattest browsers does not allow to access `getUserMedia()` if not a secure connection(https).
Solution:
1. If running your own server built in nodejs, should run in https or must run with ssl or any other certificate.
2. your Application should also be in secure server.(ie. run with https://)
3. Now, if you are following these and using a self signed certificate, you need to add that to your browser as exception. If you are running separate servers one for your own peer Server. you need to add exceptions for both the servers in the browser.
Just open one link `https://<your peer server location>:<PORT>/peerjs/id` in the browser and refresh the page.
This may solve your problem if facing the same as I. I am also looking for a better solution.
Enjoy coding.

Comment: I have the same problem but I can't solve neither with your solution. What is the peer server location which I need to type in the link you provided?

Comment: Can you share the exact error your browser might be showing in console.